# Visual studio 2015 can't build anything, even hello world console app

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have troubles with Visual studio 2015 community edition.

The installation was successful and the ide is working normally, but when I try to build any solution it gives me always this error :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(67,5): error MSB6006: "csc.exe" exited with code -2146232576.
```

I tried with the simplest hello world c# console app (created from vs template) but there is always this problem, I should mention also it takes two minutes to try compile this stupid console app before explodes with the above fatal error.

The only two things worth mentioning  about my machine are :

- I installed vs2015 on disk e: instead of c: because I have only 4GB available on c: and 140GB on e:
- I have on the same machine also vs2005 and vs2013 that run normally (I keep them for compatibility with previous projects) I always knew that multiple vs versions can run on same machine.

The machine is a win81 i3 laptop with 8GB of RAM. It works fine with all other apps including vs2005 and vs2013.

Any help really appreciated, I am getting very frustrated. I searched a lot but found no solutions.

UPDATE: it seems the reason is a problem with .NET 4, some components of vs2015 can't detect it (but it's installed) , the typical message I get is :
Version v4.0.30319 of the .NET Framework is not installed and it is required

I tried all the MS tools to repair .NET, nothing worked. It seems that I'm stuck and the only solution is re-install the whole windows and all the software fro scratch. Very frustrating, worse than the dll hell back in win31 and win95. How is possible that I cannot remove and re-install .NET4? VS2013 and all the other softwares keep working fine. But netfx_setupverifier.exe says my .net framework is damaged, so there is something.

Comment: Did you try to start Visual Studio with Administrator rights (right click run as administrator)  ?

Comment: Could you check that console project you are running as Console Application in Project > projectname settings

Comment: Try looking in Event viewer for any errors. A dying hard-disk could slow down things for an application if it tries to access a near-dead sector.

Comment: Thank you guys for your attempts. I checked all of them an unfortunately these are not the cause. I suspect the disk space could be an issue, I have 3,7 GB on C: free of 90GB and the C disk is red on explorer (low space) but  I installed the VS2015 on E: which has plenty of space. I will try to free some space on C.
Also I'm afraid I imported settings on vs2015 from vs2013 could disturb, but reinstalling doesn't solve. Wasting a lot of time I almost try to find another machine :((((